# Button hover will change the background of div and a picture in between two blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do css based hovering for background and picture to show up on hovering over a button/link inside the main div only.

The problem is that the background color is showing up all over the page and not limited to just that div block where I am trying to all these things.

here is the code:

```
<div class="suction">
<ul class="menu">
  <div class="block">
    <li><a href="#">h</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">g</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">i</a></li>
    <li class="bg"></li>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <li><a href="#">p</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">l</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">m</a></li>
    <li class="bg"></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Here is the css:

```
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
      background: #e5e5e5;
    }

suction {
        margin:0 auto;
  max-width:100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.block {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bg {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .25s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  float: ;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'HeydingsCommonIconsRegular', Helvetida Neue, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  transition: .25s;
}

li a:hover {
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
}

.ajabmenu {
  margin: 60px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block
}

.ajabmenuu li:first-child a {
  background: #ffca6d !important;
}

.ajabmenu li:nth-child(2) a {
  background: #ff6d6d !important;
}

.ajabmenu li:nth-child(3) a {
  background: #6dffb9 !important;
}

.ajabmenu li:nth-child(4) a {
  background: #6dcaff !important;
}

.ajabmenu li:nth-child(5) a {
  background: #ec6dff !important;
}

.ajabmenu li:first-child:hover ~ .bg {
  background: #ffca6d url("https://www.drupal.org/files/images/druplicon-polska-small.png") no-repeat center top fixed;
}

.ajabmenu li:nth-child(2):hover ~ .bg {
  background: #ff6d6d;
}

.ajabmenu li:nth-child(3):hover ~ .bg {
  background: #6dffb9;
}

.ajabmenu li:nth-child(4):hover ~ .bg {
  background: #6dcaff;
}

.ajabmenu li:nth-child(5):hover ~ .bg {
  background: #ec6dff;
}
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwaEqo)

Everything should be under 'suction' block and never goes out. I tried removing that Fixed from .bg but it doesnt work.

Please let me know if there is any good method or easy way to do it.

Comment: What about the image when hovering on the other li's? does it have to run in or you don't want it to show except to show it only on li's with letter h and p?

Comment: Eugen...I havent added that because I can do that later...Right now I am just focusing on keeping every action inside main div...

Comment: Can you handle this with jquery

Comment: Yes...if its light..please guide me

Answer (score 3):

Ok, first solution didn't work. Try this:

You absolutely need to lose the background color on your 'suction' class, but this codepen works.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPyWWg)

What I did was basically place the dot (.) before your 'suction' class, since it wasn't doing anything, change the background to transparent, and change the fixed position on your .bg class to absolute, and a width / height of 100%.

Here are the classes that matter:

```
.suction {
  width: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}


.bg {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .25s;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hey groooves...I did that already. I want background color changed of whole 'suction' div....so your solution is not helping. sorry...but thanks for giving it a try.

Comment: Do you mean 'section' div ? Because suction doesn't exist in your code.

Comment: Grooves sir...It work good for background color...But I am not able to see the image, as in my test environment this div comes nearly at the middle of the page so I guess the image would be hidden under logo or headbar...

Comment: The image will be at the top of your .suction div, since your .bg div is exactly the same (same position, same width, same height). If you want your image to be positioned somewhere else, you can change the 'top' property on your background declaration for something else. I think center works great, you can see it here: [Codepen with Center](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPyWWg)

Comment: Thanks groooves...I will try stuff on it. Its not working on my main test environment. Its still hidden and when I slide down then only I can see. 

But thanks a lot for your help.